# TypeScript FormGroup include dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an role class like as:
roles:

```
export class Role{
    id:number;
    roleName:string;
    description:string;

}
```

and assign role:

```
import {Role} from './roles';
    export class AssignRole{
        isActive:number;
        userRole:Role= new Role();

    }
```

on ts file, I declare form:

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      userName: new FormControl('', Validators.required,),
      firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      roles: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      address: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required,])
    });
```

In html, I want to create the roles dopdownlist

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label>Roles</label>
                      <select  class="form-control" id="roles">
                         <option formControlName="roles">

                         </option>

                     </select>
                    </div>
```

and input data to roles field:

```
this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.userService.getAssignRole(+params['id'])).subscribe(
        assignRole => {
          this.userForm.patchValue({
            roles:assignRole.userRole.roleName
          });
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

the error message is displayed: **ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'roles'**

Please advice me.

Comment: did you set `form [formGroup]="userForm"` in your html?

Comment: @SurajRao: sure, I try to change <select> to <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="roles">. The data shows well, but I want to use dropdown

Comment: you set `formcontrolname` to `option` instead of `select`..

Comment: @SurajRao: I moved from option to select, but it's blank  <select  formControlName="roles" class="form-control" id="roles" >

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML so formControlName is inside the `<select>` tag.
Then I think you would need a default value, so you don't have a blank field.

Here is an example to select the gender :

In your HTML :

```
<select class=form-control formControlName="gender" required>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
</select>
```

In your app.component.ts, you set the default value :

```
this.form= fb.group({
    gender: new FormControl('F'),
    ...
});
```

Comment: default value does not display, it's still blank

Comment: Do you have an option in your html, with the same value as the default value ?

Comment: html:  <select class=form-control formControlName="roles" required>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                </select>, and ts: roles: new FormControl('F'),

Comment: Can you create a small StackBlitz example ?